# pyschool Topic 4 Q 1

Tags: python

The task is:

> Create a function generateNumbers(num) that takes in a positive number as argument and returns a list of number from 0 to that number inclusive. Note: The function range(5) will return a list of number [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

my code:

```
def generateNumber(num):
    numbers = []
    for x in range(num):
        numbers.append(range(num+1))
        return numbers
```

What is wrong? It returns a list that looks like `[[0,1,2,3,4]]` with double `"[]"` and for `generatenumber(0)` it returns `None`...

Comment: What's the purpose of appending a `range` object to the list? Additionally, your `return` is indented incorrectly and the loop doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redundantly using `range`

You have to instead do

```
def generateNumber(num):
    numbers = []
    for x in range(num+1):
        numbers.append(x)
    return numbers         #Note where the return is
```

else the best you can do is

```
def generateNumber(num):
         return (list(range(num+1)))
```

Both will give you the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
def generateNumber(num):    
    return range(num + 1)
```

Comment: Hi dtara, and welcome to Stack Overflow. The code in your answer might be correct, but it would be a better answer with some context; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.